# Remote mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I work on a dictionary PHP project. Project owner has a dedicated server. They control server files via terminal. And they have a big database which include 370,000 words. In my program I want to connect to database. But the problem is that they don't want to upload my PHP project files to their   server. Because they fear that the database maybe stolen by others. They say you can access our mysql server via some server info and they have send some information like this:

```
server ip : xx.xxx.xxx.xx
Port=3307;
UID=xxx;
pwd=xxxx
```

The thing that I know is if I want to connect a remote mysql server, The server owner must allow my IP address or upload project files to their server.

They say we don't have a ftp interface and can't allow remote IPs. You can successfully connect via mysql connector which written in php.

Is it possible to connect to the server only with this server information if the server owner not allow to my IP address for mysql connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible (with MySQL server default configuration) to connect to a remote MySQL server instance if your user id does not have permission to connect from the remote IP to MySQL server.

If you try to connect to local MySQL server these information would suffice but if you try to connect to a remote host with these information you might get an error like this:

> "Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'aa.bb.cc.dd' (using
>   password: YES)"

This indicates that your user id does not have permission to connect to the MySQL instance from this remote IP address.

But again you can try to connect to the remote MySQL server and get a connection back. It all depends on the remote MySQL server configuration.

Comment: how can I allow remote access to the database,?

Answer (score 0):

The above information is enough to connect to MySQL server through php.

But if the server owner, has disallowed your IP for MySQL port, then you will not be able to connect.

But maybe that isn't the case, the IP disallowing can be application specific.

eg. they can disallow outside IPs to access there FTP and SSH but their MySQL port can be open for outside IP addresses hence can be accessed by you.